# How to hide UITabBar?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbar

In my app I have a tab bar. And in some views I as well have a toolbar. So when I come to those views with a toolbar it looks ugly - two bars at the bottom of the view. I thought that it would be a best solution to hide a tab bar when entering those particular views.
But I just couldn't figure out how to do it in a right way. I tried to set UITabBarController's tabBar hidden property to YES, but it didn't work. And I as well tried to do the following thing in whatever view I am:

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

But it didn't work as well.

What is the right solution to this situation? I don't want to have 2 bars at any view.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You have to use set the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property to YES on the controller that you are pushing and NOT to the UITabBarController.

```
otherController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[navigationController pushViewController: otherController animated: TRUE];
```

Or you can set the property when you first initialize the controller you want to push.

Comment: I have three view controllers that the UITabBarController can present. On the second view controller, I put `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES` in `initWithNibName:bundle:`. When I tested tapping into the second view controller, the UITabBar was still there.

Comment: Tried on a new project with ios7 - no effect

Comment: When I go back to the screen, I have a black space on top of the tab bar.

Answer (score 13):

Interface builder has checkbox for view controller embedded in tab bar - Hides bottom bar on push. In easy cases no need to do it through code now.

For @Micah

[image: Hide bottom bar on push.]

Comment: This worked for me on ios7 where setting same value in code didnt

Comment: Where is this checkbox?

Comment: Do this on the destination view controller, not the source!

Comment: could you help me on : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963911/hidesbottombarwhenpushed-weird-animation-behaviour-when-push

Answer (score 9):

**Don't use this solution!**

```
BOOL hiddenTabBar;
UITabBarController *tabBarController;

- (void) hideTabBar {

     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
     for(UIView *view in tabBarController.view.subviews)
     {
          CGRect _rect = view.frame;
          if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
          {
               if (hiddenTabBar) {
                    _rect.origin.y = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-49;
                    [view setFrame:_rect];
               } else {
                    _rect.origin.y = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
                    [view setFrame:_rect];
               }
          } else {
               if (hiddenTabBar) {
                    _rect.size.height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-49;
                    [view setFrame:_rect];
               } else {
                    _rect.size.height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
                    [view setFrame:_rect];
               }
          }
     }    
     [UIView commitAnimations];

     hiddenTabBar = !hiddenTabBar;
}
```

[Source](http://www.developers-life.com/hide-uitabbarcontrolleruitabbar-with-animation.html)

Comment: Using a custom tab bar (ALTabBar). This one worked for me. Instead to support 4" screen, I have changed 480 to [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] -> size.height

Comment: great, but... try not use fixed values like 431 or 480. You should always write code to run in any screen size!

Comment: If you want really resize the view (not only hide tabBar) set self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = hiddenTabBar;

Answer (score 9):

I too struggled with this for a while. Hiding the tab bar is one step in the right direction, but leaves a black rectangle behind. The trick is to resize the layer that backs the UIViewController's view.

I have written a small demo here with a solution:

https://github.com/tciuro/FullScreenWithTabBar

I hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome tip, wish I could upvote more.  I didn't even know there WAS a layer backing the UIViewController!

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to hide the tab bar for your current view.

You can hide it when pushing a view with the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` variable.

If you want to hide your tab bar on your current view, you can do the following:

[Gist here](https://gist.github.com/BrentMifsud/a967020dceaf4ebe28a448a049e7f67c)

Note that UIKit seems to bring the tab bar to come back on app resume. So you will have to subscribe to the notification `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification` and call the above function.