# is i need to create UINavigationController for each Tabbar?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

i have a problem is i got UItabbarController it contain 3 Tabbars 
each tabbar need to create own UINavigationController for them?

in IB it can only link UINavigationController to 1 navigationcontroller of tabbar only.
it can't multiple link.

how can i resolve for it. 
i want to hide and unhide my toolbar.
i think it it a bad idea if i must create 3 uinavigationcontroller instance variable for each tabbar.

how can i reslove this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with creating a UINavigationController for each tab in your tab bar. The answer that Marek linked to covers how to use the hidesButtonWhenPushed property. My personal preference is to create things like UINavigationControllers in code, and have them reference nib files for the actual viewControllers, but that's up to you.

Comment: okey you advise me to make an instance variable for each Uinavigation controller.

is it consume more resource?

Comment: It will consume more resources, but a negligible amount. Controllers don't take up a lot of memory, their views do.

Answer (score 1):

Answer here: [just wrote tabbar hide in google, first result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815690/hide-uitabbar)

edit: misread the english, sorry