# Easiest Way To Add In-App Internet Browser?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, webkit

I'm looking at how to make a very simple browser in my app.  Only need reload, back, forward, etc.

Does anyone have any simple code they can add here?

I have a tableviewcell that when clicked will launch this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You can use

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]]`
```

to open a website, `-reload` to reload, `– goBack` and `-goForward` to go back or forward.

Comment: Would I first create a UIWebView in IB?  Then I can push this view in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: You would create a new `UIViewController` subclass with an XIB, open the XIB in IB and then add a `UIWebView` to the view of the `UIViewController` by dragging it from the Library.

Comment: Ok, I got it all setup, I have the view loading google.com.  How would I add buttons for reload, forward, back, etc.

Comment: Just add some buttons to your `UIViewController` and add some IBActions. In these methods, you call the methods I mentioned.

Comment: Ok ill try that.  Do you know how to hid the tab bar, and replace it with a toolbar?

Comment: You might want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815690/hide-uitabbar). To show the toolbar, do `yourVC.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO`, where `yourVC` is the `UIViewController` you created. The best place to do this is probably `-viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) API, which is basically a WebKit rendering widget - the one that also powers iPhone's browser app.