# Double tap to fullscreen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is there a way to make a UIWebView recognize the double tap using a simple UITapRecognizer and to go fullscreen on double tap? I have a UINavigationBar on that screen and I want it to be hidden as well
Any ideas on how to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm... Let me work some runtime-mojo, and I'll get back to you

Comment: Have a look at this:http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/

Comment: @AIbrahimZ Thanks, I've seen this already but there's still no code to hide the NavBar and go to FullScreen mode. Which is essential to me

Comment: @SergiusGee you can hide the NavBar on touches

Comment: On touch event add this: [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];

Comment: @AIbrahimZ how about a fullscreen? How about the problems with layout that may result due to this? This is what worries me the most

Comment: You may want to ask a new question regarding the fullscreen stuff…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make the Navigation Bar hidden:

> [navBar setAlpha:0.00];

Then Use CGRect to make the webView grow to the top of the screen.

I dont know how to do double tap but i guess you could make a button and then make that Touch Down Repeat so they have to double tap it.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two good answers to that issue, which complement each-other:

- **[Navigation bar show/hide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2927038/1390251)** - answered by [Alex Reynolds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19410/alex-reynolds):
  "To hide the navigation bar:
  `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`
  ..."
- **[Hide UITabBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/815745/1390251)** - answered by [Panagiotis Korros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19331/panagiotis-korros):
  "You have to use set the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property to YES on the controller that you are pushing and NOT to the UITabBarController.
  ..."