# hidesBottomBarWhenPushed weird animation behaviour when push

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab based application,Which contains no tab bar.

For hiding tab bar i am using hidesBottomBarWhenPushed method in storyboard.

but using this my view have strength animation like : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14H3Lym0bat4kaYP5rSlFqkJp8QF1xdZm/view

The tab bar is visible for some time and then it goes down.

For the solution i have put the following code :

> self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;

in Viewwillappear but did not work.
also i have tried to hide  it programatically before push but no luck

[image]

Here is my screen which is creating issue.
I have removed all the code for hiding the tab bar, Now only hidesBottomBarWhenPushed set from storyboard.
But still getting same issue.

I have hide the Bottom bar for checking is it related to layouts, but still my whole view goes up to down for the fraction of second.

Finally I have tried :

```
 let chatRoom = ChatDetailViewController.viewController()
                    chatRoom.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatRoom, animated: true)
```

But Same result.

Here is the screenshot of animation which is happening during push:

[image]

Comment: Don't use `tabBarController.tabBar.hidden` use only `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed ` it'll hide `tabBar` when push viewcontroller and also show `tabBar` when you pop back to your controller without any extra efforts.

Comment: I am not using tabBarController.tabBar.hidden, i have removed it.but the issue is tab bar is visible for fraction of second, which is not good.

Comment: Only use `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed ` property true when push viewcontroller before the pushviewcontroller line. Remove all other hide/ show logic.

Comment: @PratikSodha i have removed all other hide/ show logic only set in storyboard, still getting the issue.

Comment: Is it related to constraints?

Comment: Are you using default `navigationBar` or custom view at Top ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178576/discussion-between-pratik-sodha-and-guru).

Comment: Did you find a solution in your private chat? private chat makes it hard for others to also find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

`viewcontroller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`

Use `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property as `true` when push viewcontroller.

> viewcontroller is object of `UIViewController` which are going to push into navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

What I have figured out facing this issue , the user (Iphone) has Reduce Motion Option in it
Setting -> Accessibility -> Motion -> Reduce Motion

If you turn the Reduce Motion "ON" it show another option of
-> Prefer Cross-Fade Tranisition

if you turn it "ON" it will cause this weird Animation when hiding Tab bar on Push.
You can detect if user turned it on or off here

[How to check if Prefer Cross-Fade Transitions is turned on in iOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483417/how-to-check-if-prefer-cross-fade-transitions-is-turned-on-in-ios-13)

and maintain push transition option accordingly.