# How to check if Prefer Cross-Fade Transitions is turned on in iOS 13?

Tags: ios

If **Reduce Motion** is turned on, we can tell by `UIAccessibility.isReduceMotionEnabled`.

Now, how about **Prefer Cross-Fade Transitions** in iOS 13?

Settings -> Accessibility -> VISION section, Motion cell -> (With Reduce Motion on) -> Prefer Cross-Fade Transitions

### Screenshot

> [image]

Comment: Where is that setting in Accessibility?

Comment: @matt Settings -> Accessibility cell -> VISION section, Motion cell -> Prefer Cross-Fade Transitions (when Reduce Motion turned on)

Comment: Cool thanks! Good explanation

Comment: @matt Thank you for looking into this, Matt. You know, I'm one of your readers. ^-^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since iOS 14.0, the property to read the **Prefer Cross-Fade Transitions** is `UIAccessibility.prefersCrossFadeTransitions`.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/3584818-preferscrossfadetransitions

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they've added this setting as a property of UIAccessibility. The way to hunt for this sort of stuff is to set a breakpoint in your app, run it, and then, when paused, say in the console

```
(lldb) ty loo UIAccessibility
```

This gives you a complete printout of the UIAccessibility class, and I don't see anything there that would suggest cross dissolves. You should probably file an enhancement request with Apple.